# How do the vortices of a fixed wing and horizontal stabilizer interact?

Tags: aerodynamics, airspeed, fixed-wing, tail, vortex

What interaction of vortices between the fixed wing and horizontal stabilizer?

How do the vortices affect the flow of the horizontal stabilizer upon leaving the wing?

when will the downwash effort affect the flow, apart from not having clean-flow?

Does the downwash decrease dynamic pressure the reduce the lift?

Does the Airflow be affected after leaving the wing?

Comment: Hi Andy, since you're new, you might not be aware, but including several questions in the same post is generally not well received, because it is easy to make the question quite broad (and thus not good for the site). Please try to focus on one specific aspect per question.

Comment: Understand what you mean, I will ask the question individually. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The vortices coming off the ends of the wing are outside the width of the stabilator or stabilizer/elevator, thus there would be little interaction.

In my plane for example, the wings are 35 feet 6 inches wide, the stabilator only 11 feet 10 inches.
Thus the end of the wing is 17.25 feet from centerline, the end of the stabilator at 5.9 feet, thus 11+ feet of clearance.
[image: Cessna Cardinal planform]

Comment: They interact, see suggested duplicate.

Comment: I disagree - I don't see the wingtip vortices interacting with the stabilizer. Maybe the wingtip and tail vortices interact with each other behind the plane somewhere, but that was not the question.

Comment: Not necessarily specific to your model, but the more powerful vortex generators on some wings definitely DO produce vortices that interact w/ the horizontal stab.

Comment: I do Agree with Jihyun. 
As the question was, How do the vortices affect the flow of the horizontal stabilizer upon leaving the wing? 

Does the downwash decrease dynamic pressure the reduce the lift?

Does the Airflow be affected after leaving the wing?